# How do I fix unbound identifier error in my brag/racket parser?

Tags: racket, dsl

I'm trying to make a parser in racket using brag.  I had a much bigger idea, but I can't get my parser to work.  Currently, my "parser.rkt" file has this simple rule:

```
#lang brag
entry-date : @digit{1,2} "-" @digit{1,2} "-" @digit{4}
digit : "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9" | "0"
```

When I test my parser I get a correct looking output:

```
(parse-to-datum "01-02-1920")
>'(entry-date "0" "1" "-" "0" "2" "-" "1" "9" "2" "0")
```

However, when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
#lang reader "accounting_reader.rkt"
01-02-1920
> *entry-date: unbound identifier in: entry-date
```

This is my tokenizer in my reader file:

```
(require brag/support)
(define (make-tokenizer port)
  (define (next-token)
    (define ac-lexer
      (lexer
       [(char-set "-1234567890") lexeme]
       [any-char (next-token)]))
    (ac-lexer port))  
  next-token)
```

Any idea why it doesn't want to work?

Comment: What does your "expander" module have?

Comment: Your intuition is correct, I found an error in my expander.  I'm pretty new to Racket, so I didn't realize how connected things could be.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in my module-begin function in my expander (missing ').  I didn't realize the error went that far into my files.  If your expander isn't correct, it won't matter what is read in.